# C++ - Optimal number of threads for processing string

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads, stdthread

I have a std::string of length **N** and I want to insert all substrings of length **K** into a std::set container, using threads. How many std::thread or pthread_t objects should I use?

Consider N = 500,000 and K = 3.

Comment: Probably as much as much core you have... but if you misuse multithreading it can actually slow down your program (at best case), so i suggest you to either learn alot about it, or stick to a single thread as long as you don't have a really good reason to use threads.

Comment: If you want optimal efficiency, probably 1.

Comment: What locking method are you planning to use when writing to the `std::set`?  You know `std::set` is not thread safe right? How frequently are you expecting to find duplicate substrings?

Comment: My aim is to find the number of times duplicate strings occur, in a multi-threaded environment, over 100 different random strings.
@ChrisDrew - I did not know that `std::set` is not thread safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [ThreadPool](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool).

It is pretty simple to use, you'll only have to `include "ThreadPool.h"` and you can set the maximum number of threads based on the number of cores available. Your code should contain the following snipet.

```
 int max_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
 ThreadPool pool(max_threads);
 auto result = pool.enqueue(func,params);
```

Here `func` is the  function to be called, `params` are the parameters and the value returned will be stored in `result`.